# WooCommerce Storefront - Why are search results not paginated?

Tags: wordpress, pagination, woocommerce

On my WordPress site, I have set up a WooCommerce store, and am using a child theme of "Storefront" for display.  I have been trying to figure out why the search results are not being paginated. I'm not even getting all results on one page.  I'm only seeing the first set of results when performing a search.

Digging into the code, it looks like the display is controlled by the `archive-product.php` file.  Why does the `search.php` file not get called by WP/WooCommerce? Also, why does pagination work correctly when viewing a product category archive, but not for search results? They are both using the same code, and I don't see any type-specific code in `archive-product.php`.

Comment: You question is too broad. Provide some code that you've done so your question will get more attraction.

Comment: I haven't done any code.  That's the point.  I would have thought that the default behavior for search result pages would be to display pagination links, as do the other pages which are generated from the same file .

Comment: Are you using the site-wide search, or the woocommerce product search? That can affect the results page.

Comment: @Aibrean - the product search.  I'm in the process of dismantling and rebuilding table by table, until I can narrow down the issue.  Ugh.

Comment: WooCommerce uses `loop_shop_per_page` to decide how many products show up per page in search. If your search results (and search uses WP default search.... ie: it is pretty crap) are fewer than the products per page, you won't see pagination.

Comment: It looks like the search box in the header (I'm using the Storefront theme) returns results to the shop base page.  The sidebar search seems to use "search.php" to display results, and pagination works correctly, there.  I have over a hundred products which match my query string, but I'm only getting the first 12, when using the header search box.  I think I have narrowed the problem to the "Shop Page Display" setting.  When set to "Show categories & subcategories", the sorting/pagination div is output with no content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooThemes was able to replicate the issue with the "Shop Page Display" setting, and a fix should be forthcoming.  Thanks, all, for your suggestions!